# Spring Mapsturct, hibernate, update nested entity (Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect))

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, mapstruct

Hi I stucked with an issue, and I cant step over it, can anyone help with it?
I use jpa, mapstruct and hibernate, for saveing multiple nested entities.
I want save and modify RealEstateColleteral entity. The createing of the entity works fine, but every time, when i want modify the entity (even if I upload the same data), I become the following error:

The exception I receive:

```
org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: Object of class [hu.claimcontrol.app.realEstateCollateral.model.OnSiteInspection] with identifier [84]: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [hu.claimcontrol.app.realEstateCollateral.model.OnSiteInspection#84]
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:315) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
  at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
  at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
  at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
  at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
  at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
  at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy171.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

The data: I want send:

```
{
    "collateralType": "PRIMARY",
    "rank": 1,
    "isLegalSafeguard": true,
    "onSiteInspections": [
        {
            "id": 84,
            "valuationDate": "2021-09-07",
            "description": "asdf",
            "inspectionDate": "2021-09-17",
            "attachments": [
                {
                    "id": 123,
                    "file": {
                        "fileId": 59,
                        "uuid": "d1469c11-9357-4f8e-bfff-4f83d7e73019",
                        "fileName": "5bb48b07fa6e3840bb3afa2bc821b882 (4).jpeg",
                        "fileSize": 58943
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 85,
            "valuationDate": "2021-09-14",
            "description": "asdf",
            "inspectionDate": "2021-09-18",
            "attachments": [
                {
                    "id": 124,
                    "file": {
                        "fileId": null,
                        "uuid": "d1469c11-9357-4f8e-bfff-4f83d7e73019",
                        "fileName": "5bb48b07fa6e3840bb3afa2bc821b882 (4).jpeg",
                        "fileSize": 58943
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 125,
                    "file": {
                        "fileId": null,
                        "uuid": "d1469c11-9357-4f8e-bfff-4f83d7e73019",
                        "fileName": "5bb48b07fa6e3840bb3afa2bc821b882 (4).jpeg",
                        "fileSize": 58943
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 126,
                    "file": {
                        "fileId": null,
                        "uuid": "d1469c11-9357-4f8e-bfff-4f83d7e73019",
                        "fileName": "5bb48b07fa6e3840bb3afa2bc821b882 (4).jpeg",
                        "fileSize": 58943
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "id": 1
}
```

If I replace the onSiteInspection and attachment id-s with null, it runs without exception

The entities:

```
// RealEstateColleteral
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "real_estate_collateral")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE real_estate_collateral SET deleted=true WHERE id=? AND version=?")
@Where(clause = "deleted=false")
public class RealEstateCollateral extends BaseEntity {

  private RealEstateCollateralType CollateralType;

  private int rank;

  private Boolean isLegalSafeguard;

  // TODO: address bekötése

  // TODO: Tulajdoni hányad bekötése

  // TODO: Fedezetértékelés bekötése

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name = "real_estate_collateral_id")
  private List<OnSiteInspection> onSiteInspections;

  // TODO: bejegyzett jog bekötése
}


// OnSiteinspection
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "on_site_inspection")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE on_site_inspection SET deleted=true WHERE id=? AND version=?")
@Where(clause = "deleted=false")
public class OnSiteInspection extends BaseEntity {

  private LocalDate valuationDate;

  private LocalDate inspectionDate;

  @Column(length = 500)
  private String description;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name = "on_site_inspection_id")
  private List<Attachment> attachments;
}

// Attachment
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
@Table(name = "file_atachment")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE file_atachment SET deleted=true WHERE id=? AND version=?")
@Where(clause = "deleted=false")
public class Attachment extends BaseEntity {

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "file_view_id")
  private FileView file;
}

// FileView
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
@Table(name = "file_view")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE file_view SET deleted=true WHERE id=? AND version=?")
@Where(clause = "deleted=false")
public class FileView extends BaseEntity {

  private Integer fileId;
  private String uuid;
  private String fileName;
  private Integer fileSize;
}
```

The dto-s (I use swagger to generate them from yaml file)

```
 RealEstateCollateralType:
      type: string
      enum:
        - PRIMARY
        - ADDITIONAL

    AttachmentDto:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int32
        file:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/FileDto'


    OnSiteInspectionDto:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int32
        valuationDate:
          type: string
          format: date
        description:
          type: string
        inspectionDate:
          type: string
          format: date
        attachments:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/AttachmentDto'

    RealEstateCollateralRequest:
      type: object
      properties:
        collateralType:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/RealEstateCollateralType'
        rank:
          type: integer
          format: int32
        isLegalSafeguard:
          type: boolean
        onSiteInspections:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/OnSiteInspectionDto'

    RealEstateCollateralResponse:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/RealEstateCollateralRequest'
        - type: object
          properties:
            id:
              type: integer
              format: int32

    FileDto:
      type: object
      properties:
        fileId:
          type: integer
          format: int32
        uuid:
          type: string
          maxLength: 255
        fileName:
          type: string
          maxLength: 255
        fileSize:
          type: integer
          maxLength: int64
```

The mapper for the entity

```
// DtoMapper
import org.mapstruct.MappingTarget;

public interface DtoMapper<Entity, Request, Response> {

  Entity requestToEntity(Request request);

  Response entityToResponse(Entity entity);

  void updateFromRequest(Request request, @MappingTarget Entity entity);
}

// updateRealEstateCollateral
  public RealEstateCollateralResponse updateRealEstateCollateral(
      Integer realEstateCollateralId, RealEstateCollateralRequest realEstateCollateralRequest) {
    RealEstateCollateral realEstateCollateral = getRealEstateCollateralById(realEstateCollateralId);

    realEstateCollateralMapper.updateFromRequest(realEstateCollateralRequest, realEstateCollateral);

    realEstateCollateral = realEstateCollateralRepository.save(realEstateCollateral);
    log.info("RealEstateCollateral updated with id: {}", realEstateCollateral.getId());

    return realEstateCollateralMapper.entityToResponse(realEstateCollateral);
  }
```

Repostitory:

```
// RealEstateColleteralRepository
  @Repository
public interface RealEstateCollateralRepository
    extends JpaRepository<RealEstateCollateral, Integer>,
        QuerydslPredicateExecutor<RealEstateCollateral>,
        QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QRealEstateCollateral> {
  @Override
  default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QRealEstateCollateral root) {
    bindings
        .bind(String.class)
        .first((StringPath path, String value) -> path.containsIgnoreCase(value));
    bindings.excluding(
        root.created,
        root.createdBy,
        root.lastModified,
        root.lastModifiedBy,
        root.id,
        root.version);
  }
}
```

Sorry for coping so many code, but I have not exactly idea, where should I search the mistake.
Im not sure, that I'm following the best practice, if not please let me know, and I will rewrite it with an other perspective.

Thank you for help (by the way this is my first stackoverflow post :-) )

Answer (score 1):

You get the `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException` when the version number in your entity differs from the version number in your database. If you look at the database queries being made you will see the version is in the where clause. When updating with versioning you first find the entity using a repository method. This pulls in it's current version. You then update the entity data, and save. Doing so will ensure the version number matches what's in the database unless another transaction has updated the same entity between the time you performed the find and the save (a true `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException` scenario).